# Difference between Release and Debug?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, while-loop, backgroundworker, release

I get an very strange behaviour when I change my Visual Studio 2010 config from Debug to Release:

I have a `BackgroundWorker`: `_bg`, in the `DoWork` I have:

```
                iswaiting = true;
                _bg.ReportProgress(1, filePath);
                while (iswaiting)
                {                        
                  ;
                }
                //My other part of code (EDIT: something do to with the `result` I get from the user.)
```

in the `ProgressChanged` I have a `MessageBox` and after the user interaction, `iswaiting` will be set back to false and the `_bg` `DoWork` program will continue.

```
 void _bg_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //my other part of code........
       result = Microsoft.Windows.Controls.MessageBox.Show("Question" ,"Title", MessageBoxButton.YesNoCancel, MessageBoxImage.Warning);

       iswaiting=false; 
       log(iswaiting.toString());                  
    }
```

All of these works very well when I run it from Visual Studio or build in *Debug* mode, but when I build it to *Release*, I never get out of the `while(iswaiting)` loop, although I can see from the log `iswaiting` is already set back to `false`.

**EDIT**:

**Better way of doing this is more than welcome!!**

Comment: Eeeep, you probably should think of a different way of implementing this the while loop could get CPU intensive

Comment: I don't see anything creating a memory barrier here. Debug limits certain optimizations that in this case removes the need for it, but a Release build will require it.

Comment: I know this is not the issue, but why are you waiting? You could just do the code you wait for in your progress changed method. Or you might event be able to do it on your BackgroundWorkerCompleted event.

Comment: This is a side-effect of optimizations done by the x86 jitter.  The iswaiting variable must be declared volatile.

Comment: @BenjaminDangerJohnson From looking at his code, it appears that he's waiting for the user to indicate whether it should continue or stop early, so moving the rest of `DoWork` to `ProgressChanged` or `Completed` might not be the right solution.

Comment: @Servy Maybe, but if he checks the result of the dialog in progress changed, he can simply do an asychronus cancel. If he can't allow cancellation then many using a background worker is not the optimal solution in this situation.

Comment: @BenjaminDangerJohnson The problem with trying to cancel is that you don't know how much more the BGW will process from the time of the popup until the cancellation is noticed.  If doing "extra" work is okay, then that's fine, but if it's not then you're still left with the problem of waiting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is likely due to threading optimizations.  In order to safely "see" the change in `iswaiting` in release mode, you need a memory barrier in place.

The simplest way to "fix" this would be to mark `iswaiting` as [`volatile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x13ttww7.aspx):

```
volatile bool iswaiting;
```

That being said, "spinning" like this will completely consume one CPU core.  A much better approach would be to use a `ManualResetEvent` to signal that you can continue.

```
// Add:
private ManualResetEvent allowProgress = new ManualResetEvent(false);
```

Then, instead of using iswaiting, you'd do:

```
_bg.ReportProgress(1, filePath);
allowProgress.WaitOne(); // This will block until it's set
```

To allow this to continue, use:

```
 result = Microsoft.Windows.Controls.MessageBox.Show("Question" ,"Title", MessageBoxButton.YesNoCancel, MessageBoxImage.Warning);

  allowProgress.Set();
```

The advantage here is that you won't consume CPU while you're blocked, and you don't have to worry about the memory barriers yourself.

Comment: Thanks a lot! `ManualResetEvent` works great! Just one more question I need to set 'allowProgress = new ManualResetEvent(false);' every time I use `allowProgress.WaitOne(); `. I can't just reuse `allowProgress.WaitOne(); ` after `allowProgress.Set(); ` ?

Comment: @Bolu You can call Reset on `allowProgress` to make it "block" again: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.eventwaithandle.reset.aspx  Alternatively, there is also an `AutoResetEvent` class (depending on the scenario, it may work better)

Comment: I have tried them and this can be solved with either `Reset` and `AutoResetEvent`! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5):

So your problem is likely that you are using a boolean field, and you haven't marked it as `volatile`.  Because of this, certain optimizations (often only applied in release mode) can result in both threads accessing a copy of the field that is local to their thread (possibly on the cache of their core of the processor, for example).

However, marking the field `volatile` isn't really a good idea here.  You have a more fundamental problem in that you're performing a spinwait, which is virtually always a bad idea.  You should use a method that actually pauses the thread until it is supposed to continue.  One way would be to use a `ManualResetEvent` or a `Semaphore`.

Looking at your code, what you're waiting on is for the user to dismiss a message box fired in the progress changed event.  I would say that, rather than having this in the progress changed event, you should simply include it in the actual "do work" event.  It is desirable for the doWork method to not care about the progress changed event once it's fired.

Comment: I have eventually moved the user interaction part to the DoWork event directly by using Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke to show MessageBox. Am I doing this correctly?

Comment: @Bolu Well, it sort of defeats the purpose of a BGW if you don't leverage its ability to marshal events to the UI thread, but what you're don't isn't really wrong per say.  It's certainly way better than what you were doing in the code in the question.

Answer (score 0):

A much better approach would be to use a Semaphore signal that you can continue.

```
private Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(1, 1000);
semaphore.WaitOne();
```

and after you want to release

```
semaphore.Release();
```

Comment: Why is a semaphore a better choice ?

Comment: it's better approach than bool.and it's very easy to use and finally it's assurance.